# Eclipse Juno : Where is the Hibernate Code Generation menu item?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno, eclipse-indigo

In eclipse `Indigo` and below, there used to be a Code Generation menu:

[image: Indigo]

I can't seem to find it in Eclipse `Juno`..

[image: Juno]

Where is it ? am I missing something ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check whether you can enable it yourself via Window -> Customize Perspective -> Menu Visibility -> Run.

Comment: I tried this the first time, it didn't work. I just had to switch back to another perspective and return to hibernate perspective. And it worked fine. Thanks.